# Sutherland-Hodgman homogeneous clipping

Tags: python, rendering

I am currently working on a rendering application in Python for self-educational purposes. Most aspects seem clear, but I am encountering difficulties with the clipping part. I have referred to several articles that discuss clipping in clip space (after the Projection matrix and before perspective division). However, the results I am getting seem incorrect.

For instance, when setting up the camera position with x=2, y=1, z=2, the resulting image is not as expected. I have provided an image for reference: [Clipping issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFOK.png)
The expectation is that the near clipping plane should be horizontal.

To further illustrate the problem, when I set the camera position to x=0, y=1, z=2, the resulting image is [Image with x=0, y=1, z=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBzZU.png), where the near clipping plane appears horizontal, aligning with expectations.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on resolving this clipping issue in my Python rendering application. Thank you in advance for your help!

I've tried clipping in NDC space but result remains the same.
What I am missing?